# Can timeline and network models be combined?

Tags: vis.js

I am looking to outline a set of nodes that are created over time, and related to each other. D3 has a way to render nodes over time, and I could try to add links to this model. 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6526445e2b44303eebf21da3b6627320

I'd like to use vis.js for this... where I distribute nodes based on their time of creation, and connect them to each other based on their relationships.

Then, asking for the impossible, I will ask that one cannot move them on the X axis but can move them on the Y-axis, to be able to analyze what is going on...

Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would add this as a comment but I dont have a high enough reputation. I saw a similar question where the user was wanting to combine the timeline and graph2d module together. I hope it can help point you in the right direction.

[How to draw line graph on timeline using visjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596816/how-to-draw-line-graph-on-timeline-using-visjs)